# SSH as another user, run commands and exit

Tags: bash, ssh

Lets say I am userA and I am trying to SSH as userB, run multiple commands on remote host and exit. I cannot ssh as myself to the host.

I wrote the following bash script and it has two issues. 
1)Until loop is not echoing anything when the server is down and never exits the loop when the server is up
2)When the server is up and I run the script, ssh session doesn't exit

```
#!/bin/bash

until ssh userB@IP; do
    echo "Trying again..."
done

ssh -tT userB@IP << EOF
  echo 'test' > test
EOF
```

Please suggest any corrections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the first ssh, consider

```
ssh -o ConnectionAttempts=1 -o ConnectTimeout=10 user@IP exit
```

so you don't

1. wait too long or try too many times before getting your echo command and
2. open a connection you have to manually close.

Comment: Works great! thanks. Still have to figure out the second part

Comment: -T and -t do opposite things (disable pseudo-terminal, force pseudo-terminal). I don't think either is required for what you're doing. Try just `ssh user@host << EOF ....`

Comment: That's actually true. When I don't use -T, I get this extra output `Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.` To avoid that, I've been using -T. I picked -t somewhere on the web when script wasn't working.